# How to Make the Opacity of my white background 20%

Tags: joomla-3.x, css, jhtml

How do I go about making the Opacity of my white background 20%? You can view the white background i'm talking about here,

http://www.webbmaster.com.au/web-programs/questdesign/index.php/folio

This is my css so far,

```
.foliopage {
background: #fff; // Left as a fallback for older browsers
background: rgba(255,255,255,0.7); // transparent white
color: #000;
}
```

Many thanks if you can help me out.

Comment: This isn't really a Joomla problem it's a css problem. Answer can be found here css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support I gave -1 because this question shows very little research.

Comment: Have you tried adding !important

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a simple CSS problem and shows no research effort at all. This question would be better suited to stackoverflow (except that a simple search on there would likely already provide the answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your fallback needs to go after the default state, like so:

```
.foliopage {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.7); // transparent white
    background: #fff; // Left as a fallback for older browsers
    color: #000;
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the fallback needs to be first or everything will just use the second (valid) style. The correct answer is that the `0.7` needs to be `0.2` if it should be `20% transparent` (or maybe `0.8`?)

Comment: I believe you're right and I've always put the fallback first, however when editing the source CSS on his website, putting it after seems to work. Might just be my Firebug/FF Beta playing up

Comment: Huh, in Chrome, I was just getting a solid bg if the fallback was second. Also, the styling should "cascade", so the second one _should_ override the first